# Template layouts in revel

Tags: go, revel

Is it possible to use template layouts in Revel. For example have a root.html which contains a `{{define "main"}}{{end}}` tag. Then call `ExecuteTemplate(out, "main", nil)` http://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#Template.ExecuteTemplate

Something like c.RenderLayout()

Answer (score 0):

You can define the do you want into conf/routes file.
Then you can call you action with the name you want:

```
package controllers
import (
  "github.com/revel/revel"
)
func (c Name) root() revel.Result {
c.Render()
}
```

views/Name/root.html

Other way can be this:

views/Controler/NameAction.html

```
{{template "root.html" .}}
```

views/root.html

```
<p>bla, bla</p>
```